# How do I debug libcurl to solve IMAP problem

Tags: debugging, imap, eclipse-cdt, libcurl

I am developing my own IMAP application to read and process specific email messages from an email server using IMAP. My development environment is Ubuntu 20 LTS, using *eclipse-CDT*.

I had decided to use libcurl as the interface to the email server, because I had used it successfully on another project. My problem was that I was not able to see all of the response, when I made an IMAP fetch (eg. `FETCH 4 (BODY.PEEK[1])`). I could see that libcurl was correctly corresponding with the server, and that (by enabling the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option), I could indeed see that libcurl was receiving the 'missing' message text from the email server. I obviously needed to persuade libcurl to give me the 'missing' details.

The question was: How? With the installed version of libcurl, I could not debug into libcurl from my program, because the installed version of libcurl did not have debug symbols. My solution is below.

Answer (score 1):

The source code of curl is available from https://curl.se/. My first attempt was to install the latest version of Curl and use `sudo make install` to install the curl libraries over the in system already installed libraries. This was not successful, and I had to use a backup to recover my Ubuntu system from a savepoint that I had made a couple of days before. Luckily I am somewhat paranoid about backups! I then downloaded the curl sources corresponding to the version of curl already installed in my Ubuntu system, and compiled them in a local directory using the `./configure --enable-debug` option, to produce a debug version of libcurl with debug symbols. The next problem was to persuade eclipse to load my local version of libcurl rather than the system version.

The solution is in two stages:

- First set the *eclipse* project to include the local version of libcurl, as illustrated in the following image:[image]
- Now set the linux `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in the debug configuration for your project in *eclipse* to point to the local directory containing libcurl.so, as illustrated in the following image: [image]

One can then use the linux command `ldd` to check that the program is loading the correct version of libcurl.so. Please remember, though, to change the illustrated paths to fit your development environment.

I could then debug into the curl code. After a little debugging, I was able to find the solution to my problem - the 'missing' IMAP details are reported using the callback function set with the curl option `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`. Implementing this callback function gave me the 'missing' message data.